# Running multiple C# classes in one project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a C# project in Visual Studio which has several classes under it. I am trying to run each class separately but when ever I hit the start or debug buttons,only one of the classes (the first one I created) runs.I tried right-clicking the other classes but they don't have the run option. I am using Visual Studio   Express 2013

**Update (To clarify the question)**

[image]

Under the `Solution` C-SharpTutorial i have two `.cs` files (ArrayTest.cs and Program.cs). What am asking is if it's possible to run these files separately. Right now, I am only able to run the `Program.cs` file which is the first one i created.

Comment: put a `static void Main(string[] args)`-Method in your ArrayTest then in the Project Settings you can set the startup object to ArrayTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by *classes*  you actually mean *projects*. Because one Solution contains one or more projects, and projects can be run.

The answer to that is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx

> #### To set a single startup project
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the desired startup project within your solution.
> 2. On the Project menu, choose Set as StartUp Project.

Otherwise, please clarify your question.

---

Okay, i assume you have a console application. While you cannot "run classes", you can set a startup method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49585943/1974021

A class is a set of methods. To execute (non-static) methods, a class must be instantiated. But the runtime does not know how to call an arbitrary constructor. Therefore, the program execution starts in a static method called "Main".

If multiple classes contain a suitable Main() method, you should be able to select the desired one according to the link above.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.Thanks.

Comment: The link is broken as of 2018.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean *Projects*, not *Classes*.  To change the project that is executed when you start debug mode, you can right click on the project and select "Set Active Project".

If you set breakpoints in any of the other projects that are referenced, they will still be hit and you will be able to debug using Visual Studio.

If you need to run multiple projects, you will need to run these manually from the *bin\Debug* folder, and then use the "Attach To Process" feature in Visual Studio to attach the debugger to those processes so that you can debug them.

**Update**

No, you cannot 'run' two different classes separately.  A console application has only one entry point.  However, if you're learning C# and testing code, you can use a switch statement.

For example:

```
void main()
{
    Console.Write("Choose Option (1/2):");
    var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    switch (key)
    {
        case "1":
        {
            var arrayTest = new ArrayTest();
            arrayTest.Run();
            break;
        }
        case "2":
        {
            var anotherTest = new AnotherTest();
            anotherTest.Run();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, when the app runs it will prompt you for a key, and you can press 1 or 2 to execute whatever you want.

With that said, for writing basic test code, I find using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) significantly more productive as it bypasses the need of writing all of the boilerplate console application code.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to clarify my question until now.Please take a look at the update.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu Thanks for clarifying.  Will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Seeing this after all this time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of reasons for this:

1. Every class has their own `Main()` method.
2. C# is case-sensitive, so method names like `Main()` are not like `main()` and won't show in the project properties window.

Solution: Keep as startup project under project properties --> Application --> select a project which you want run.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Reasons

1. Every Class have their own Main() Method

2.C# has case sensitive so method name like Main() not like main() it won't show in project properties window

---->Kept as startup project under project properties-->> Application--->
select a project which u want run