# How to set startup object in console application in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I know this is not tough but still I am facing a problem, I have created one console application Named Console Application, Under this application, there are two class one is Program.cs, Delegate.cs. When I am trying to run Delegate.cs but always running Program.cs. Even I tried to set the startup object from properties But there Delegate.cs is not appearing in Drop Down List. 
A code is here---

```
class program
{
   public static  void Main()
   {
    Console.WriteLine("I am from program.cs");
   }

}

class Delegate
{
   public static  void Main()
   {
    Console.WriteLine("I am from Delegate.cs");
   }
}
```

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you need to:

1. Compile first (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)
2. Use another word instead of *Delegate*
3. Try giving your method an args parameter `Main(string[] args)`

It works for me:
[image]

Comment: I have tried by changing the name of class even I compiled but still not showing in the Dropdown list. is there a solution to this?

Comment: Try clean solution, or try do it in a fresh solution.

Comment: What happens if you leave it as (Not Set) please?

Comment: After adding Delegate class comment out Main method in Program class. Make sure you add main method in Delegate class "static void Main(string[] args)". Compile the project, then verify Startup object it will display, delegate class. Now delegate class would be visible in startup object. The reason we have to do this as it does not allow to add multiple main methods in both class. Later you can uncomment Program cs class and both classes are now available to select as Startup object.