# How to change startup code in Visual Studio for c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Every time I start a new project in visual studio with c# it start with something like this
[image: Image 1]

But I want it to be like this every time i create a new project
[image: Image 2]
So how do I change this?
PS: I'm totally new in programming so forgive me for any mistake.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019 How to create project templates

Comment: Your question has asked before. Follow this: [How to set startup object in console application in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49585823/how-to-set-startup-object-in-console-application-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you basically want to create a project template.

Project template helps you to start with the custom changes that you already made to a project.

1. Create the deafault project and make changes in it as you may need it in the future.
2. Go to Project --> Export Template...
3. From the window select Project Template and choose the current Project name, click next.
4. Name the Template and destination and Click Finish.